# When a checkbox is checked the multiple textboxes become visible however I need a second activity

Tags: excel, checkbox, multiple-instances

I have working code to show and hide some text boxes etc, however I wanna have the text which is filled in one of those text boxes appears in a cell. Actually 2 text box values separate by a comma in one cell.

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
If CheckBox2 Then
    ComboBox151.Visible = True
    TextBox227.Visible = True
    TextBox228.Visible = True
    Label358.Visible = True
    Label359.Visible = True
    TextBox_combi.Visible = True
    comments.Visible = True
Else
    ComboBox151.Visible = False
    TextBox227.Visible = False
    TextBox228.Visible = False
    Label358.Visible = False
    Label359.Visible = False
    TextBox_combi.Visible = False
    comments.Visible = False
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: So include another line of code if checkbox2 is checked to write the textbox values?

Comment: Yes, that is the wish but then the value of 2 textboxes in one cell

Comment: `Sheets(1).Cells(1,1) = Me.Textbox1.value & ", " & Me.Textbox2.value` ???

Comment: Sorry for asking dumb question, I am not a coder but can't get it work. I tried `Sheets("Visit 1").Cells(F28, 1) = Me.TextBox227.Value & ", " & Me.TextBox228`.Value but don't know how  and where to put it in the code.

Comment: `Sheets("Visit 1").Cells(28, 6) = Me.TextBox227.Value & ", " & Me.TextBox228`. I don't know your purpose or code so implement to your needs.